# Contact geometry: approximation of Legendrian mappings

Tags: contact-geometry, heisenberg-groups

Let $\alpha$ be a standard contact form on $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$. We say that a map $f:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ *contact* if $f^*\alpha=0$.

> **Question 1.** Is it true that a $C^1$-contact immersion can be approximated (locally in the supremum norm) by $C^\infty$-contact
>   immersion?
>
> **Question 2.** Is it true that a $C^1$-contact map $f:\mathbb{R}^{k}\to\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ can be approximated (locally in
>   the supremum norm) by $C^\infty$-contact maps?

In the case of question 2 I do not pose any restrictions on how large $k$ is. 
I expect that the answer to question 2 is in the negative and I would like to know if it is known or not.

I am also interested in other variants of the questions stated above.